# Gsheets package not importing

Tags: flutter, google-sheets, importerror

I'm trying to use gsheets in my flutter project, but every time I try to import it by writing `import 'package:gsheets/ghsheets.dart';` the package it's underlined in red and gives me this error:

`Error: Could not resolve the package 'gsheets' in 'package:gsheets/ghsheets.dart'. lib/main.dart:2:8: Error:  Not found: 'package:gsheets/ghsheets.dart'import 'package:gsheets/ghsheets.dart';    ^Unhandled exception: FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:package%3Agsheets%2Fghsheets.dart; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs) #0  StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7) #1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:657:37)              #2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:825:21)     <asynchronous suspension>                                                #3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:583:15) <asynchronous suspension>                                       #4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:43:22) #5      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:180:27)     #6      main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:13:30) #7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32) #8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)`

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: did you imported it in pubspac,yaml?

Comment: No, how do I do that?  (Also sorry for the late response)

Comment: I figured it out!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: you're welcome ,